# How to integrate spring beans and struts2?

Tags: spring, struts2, javabeans

Given below is the stack trace and I have been stuck with this problem for long time now, from the trace i could just make out that there was some problem in properly wiring up spring bean with struts for dependency injection using maven as the build tool.
Here baseAction if the name of the ACTION class.

```
2011-07-09 21:28:52,766 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@fdb413], property=struts]
2011-07-09 21:28:52,767 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Creating an DefaultActionProxy for namespace / and action name base
2011-07-09 21:28:52,768 DEBUG [DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:385] : No bean named 'com.app.action.BaseAction' found in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@169df00: defining beans [userService]; root of factory hierarchy
2011-07-09 21:28:52,769 DEBUG [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1039] : Not autowiring property 'actionErrors' of bean 'com.app.action.BaseAction' by name: no matching bean found
2011-07-09 21:28:52,769 DEBUG [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1039] : Not autowiring property 'actionMessages' of bean 'com.app.action.BaseAction' by name: no matching bean found
2011-07-09 21:28:52,770 DEBUG [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1039] : Not autowiring property 'fieldErrors' of bean 'com.app.action.BaseAction' by name: no matching bean found
2011-07-09 21:28:52,770 DEBUG [AbstractBeanFactory.java:214] : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'userService'
2011-07-09 21:28:52,771 DEBUG [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1033] : Added autowiring by name from bean name 'com.app.action.BaseAction' via property 'userService' to bean named 'userService'
2011-07-09 21:28:52,771 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : intercept '//base' { 
2011-07-09 21:28:52,772 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : applied invocation context locale=en_US
2011-07-09 21:28:52,772 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : before Locale=en_US
2011-07-09 21:28:52,772 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : cannot find method [prepareExecute] in action [com.app.action.BaseAction@10812ac]
2011-07-09 21:28:52,773 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : cannot find method [prepareDoExecute] in action [com.app.action.BaseAction@10812ac]
2011-07-09 21:28:52,773 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Setting static parameters {}
2011-07-09 21:28:52,774 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Setting params NONE
2011-07-09 21:28:52,774 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Setting params 
2011-07-09 21:28:52,775 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Invoking validate() on action com.app.action.BaseAction@10812ac
2011-07-09 21:28:52,776 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : cannot find method [validateExecute] in action [com.app.action.BaseAction@10812ac]
2011-07-09 21:28:52,776 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : cannot find method [validateDoExecute] in action [com.app.action.BaseAction@10812ac]
2011-07-09 21:28:52,777 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Executing action method = null
2011-07-09 21:28:55,023 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@fdb413], property=struts]
2011-07-09 21:28:55,024 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Creating an DefaultActionProxy for namespace / and action name base
2011-07-09 21:28:55,024 DEBUG [DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:385] : No bean named 'com.app.action.BaseAction' found in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@169df00: defining beans [userService]; root of factory hierarchy
2011-07-09 21:28:55,025 DEBUG [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1039] : Not autowiring property 'actionErrors' of bean 'com.app.action.BaseAction' by name: no matching bean found
2011-07-09 21:28:55,026 DEBUG [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1039] : Not autowiring property 'actionMessages' of bean 'com.app.action.BaseAction' by name: no matching bean found
2011-07-09 21:28:55,026 DEBUG [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1039] : Not autowiring property 'fieldErrors' of bean 'com.app.action.BaseAction' by name: no matching bean found
2011-07-09 21:28:55,027 DEBUG [AbstractBeanFactory.java:214] : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'userService'
2011-07-09 21:28:55,027 DEBUG [AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1033] : Added autowiring by name from bean name 'com.app.action.BaseAction' via property 'userService' to bean named 'userService'
2011-07-09 21:28:55,028 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : intercept '//base' { 
2011-07-09 21:28:55,029 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : applied invocation context locale=en_US
2011-07-09 21:28:55,029 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : before Locale=en_US
2011-07-09 21:28:55,030 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : cannot find method [prepareExecute] in action [com.app.action.BaseAction@b17e0a]
2011-07-09 21:28:55,031 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : cannot find method [prepareDoExecute] in action [com.app.action.BaseAction@b17e0a]
2011-07-09 21:28:55,031 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Setting static parameters {}
2011-07-09 21:28:55,032 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Setting params NONE
2011-07-09 21:28:55,032 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Setting params 
2011-07-09 21:28:55,037 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Invoking validate() on action com.app.action.BaseAction@b17e0a
2011-07-09 21:28:55,037 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : cannot find method [validateExecute] in action [com.app.action.BaseAction@b17e0a]
2011-07-09 21:28:55,038 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : cannot find method [validateDoExecute] in action [com.app.action.BaseAction@b17e0a]
2011-07-09 21:28:55,038 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:57] : Executing action method = null
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What error do you see when trying to execute the action?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think all of that log is fluff except for this line:

```
2011-07-09 21:28:52,768 DEBUG [DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:385] : No bean named 'com.app.action.BaseAction'
found in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@169df00: defining beans [userService];
root of factory hierarchy
```

When spring says it cannot find a bean with that name, I believe it is telling you that it has not been informed of such a bean.

Check in the spring **context.xml** (perhaps `WEB-INF/spring/web-application-context.xml`) file and add a

```
<bean id="com.app.action.BaseAction" class="com.app.action.BaseAction" />
```

declaration for your bean.